# How to make AddRange type-safe

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, generics, compile-time

I have this dummy code in `vb.net`

```
Sub dummy()
    Dim a = New List(Of XDocument)
    Dim b = New List(Of Net.Mail.MailAddress)
    b.AddRange(a)
End Sub
```

Obviously, this cant ever work. but the compiler ignores it.

How can I force `VS` to flag this at compile time?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The compiler only allows that because you have `Option Strict Off`. You should basically ALWAYS have `Option Strict On` at the project level and only set it `Off` at the file level on the very rare occasions that you actually need to use late-binding. Even then, you should only set it `Off` in those specific files that actually require it and you should use partial classes to keep the code in those files to an absolute minimum.

Set `Option Strict On` in your project properties and the compiler will correctly flag that as bad code and there's every chance that you'll see other problem areas highlighted too. You should also set it `On` in the VS options, so that it will be `On` by default for all future projects.